# Not able to cast data into Dictionary

Tags: ios, json, swift, casting

I have a JSONObject and I want to cast it as its class.

I tried using JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options: []
and encoding it as .utf8 String without success....

```swift
 socket.on("privateMessage") {data, ack in

            print("privateMessage :\(data[0])");

            guard let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options: []) else {return}
```

Result:

```swift
(lldb) po data
▿ 1 element
  - 0 : {"emisor":105,"receptor":54,"receptor_token":"7ec66175309aac4cbeda0c9936991cfdfcad8445fdcff583524d940c7e0ee4669488675c214823e0","texto":"Dshfljkhdlsafh","updated_at":"2019-06-20 16:38:30","created_at":"2019-06-20 16:38:30","id":10056,"time":"16:38:30"}

(lldb) po jsonData
▿ 282 bytes
  - count : 282
  ▿ pointer : 0x00007f917289f000
    - pointerValue : 140262668627968
```

Comment: please `print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!` and add the result to the question

Comment: Throw error ```Cannot convert value of type '[Any]' to expected argument type 'Data' ```           So                ```guard let stringData = data[0] as? String else {return}```         returns                                                                                                                   ```"{\"emisor\":105,\"receptor\":54,\"receptor_token\":\"6b6295e0b0601146e56ff4a9caec287f0ecc0f385fcfcd758dccd00c6385c558eefc6d6fbe98e977\",\"texto\":\"Blanca bla\",\"updated_at\":\"2019-06-21 10:48:22\",\"created_at\":\"2019-06-21 10:48:22\",\"id\":10074,\"time\":\"10:48:22\"}" ```

Comment: I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a very unusual response format, from the output in the comment it's an unspecified array (`[Any]`) containing one JSON string, like this

```
let json = """
{"emisor":105,"receptor":54,"receptor_token":"6b6295e0b0601146e56ff4a9caec287f0ecc0f385fcfcd758dccd00c6385c558eefc6d6fbe98e977","texto":"Blanca bla","updated_at":"2019-06-21 10:48:22","created_at":"2019-06-21 10:48:22","id":10074,"time":"10:48:22"}
"""

let data : [Any] = [json]
```

---

First of all for convenience declare a struct

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    let emisor, receptor, id: Int
    let receptorToken, texto, updatedAt, createdAt, time: String
}
```

To parse the JSON check if `data` is an array and if there is one string in the array, on success convert it to `Data` and decode it with `Decodable`

```
socket.on("privateMessage") {data, ack in
    if let response = data as? [Any], let jsonString = response.first as? String {
       let jsonData = Data(jsonString.utf8)
       do {
           let decoder = JSONDecoder()
           decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
           let result = try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: jsonData)
           print(result)
       } catch {
           print(error)
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I found the issue! It was a source format matter: the object wasn't parsed before being sent. Now its working with:  ```print("privateMessage :\(data[0])");
            
            guard let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data[0], options: .prettyPrinted) else {return}


            guard let message = try? JSONDecoder().decode(myMessage.self, from: jsonData) else {
                ack.with("Error message ")
                return
            }``` Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

This way you can get Data of any key. I am showing you the example of getting receptor_token key value.

```
if let response = jsonData as? [Any] {
    if let responseData = response[0] as? [String:Any] {
       if let receptorToken = responseData["texto"] as? String {
             print(receptorToken)
       }

    }

}
```

Comment: I’m sorry but this is the first thing that I tried and it doesn’t ley me cast it as a dic(throws nil). I think that colud be something related with its string codification but I don’t know what.